# How to extract parent and nested items in single regular expression?

Tags: regex

I want to use regular expression to match the following html table:

```
<tbody class=\"DocTableBody \">
  <tr data-fastRow=\"1\" class=\"DataRow TDRE\">
    <td  id=\"g-f-1\" class=\"TDC  FieldDisabled Field TCLeft   CellText  g-f\"   >
      <div class=\"DTC\">
        <label id=\"c_g-f-1\" class=\"DCC\" >01-Apr-2015</label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td  id=\"g-g-1\" class=\"TDC  FieldDisabled Field TCLeft   CellTextHtml  g-g\"   >
      <div class=\"DTC\">
        <label id=\"c_g-g-1\" class=\"DCC\" >ACTIVE</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-fastRow=\"2\" class=\"DataRow TDRO\">
    <td  id=\"g-f-2\" class=\"TDC  FieldDisabled Field TCLeft   CellText  g-f\"   >
      <div class=\"DTC\">
        <label id=\"c_g-f-2\" class=\"DCC\" >01-Apr-2015</label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td  id=\"g-g-2\" class=\"TDC  FieldDisabled Field TCLeft   CellTextHtml  g-g\"   >
      <div class=\"DTC\">
        <label id=\"c_g-g-2\" class=\"DCC\" >ACTIVE</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I expected to extract the following value:

```
"1"
  01-Apr-2015
  ACTIVE
"2"
  01-Apr-2015
  ACTIVE
```

I tried the following to extract the value in `data-fastRow`:

```
(?sUi)<tr data-fastRow=\\"(\d+)\\".+>.*<\/tr>
```

But I couldn't extract the nested items in `<label.+>(.*)</label>` in single regular expression.

Is that possible to extract parent and nested items in single regular expression?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: @Jan: I am using Delphi 10.1 Berlin.

Answer (score 0):

It's a really bad idea to parse HTML with regular expressions.
Each languahe has its own libraries to parse HTML.
In Python for example you have [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

It's by far much better to use such libraries.

Usually, such libraries has jQuery-Selector-like interface (or something like that), which allows you to find your data with extremely easy queries.